# How do I handle multiple PHP sessions with one user on a single server?

Tags: php, facebook, session-state

I have few Facebook Apps hosted on a single domain on my server. It is possible that the same user may access two or more of my apps in a single session. How do I make sure that some data from one app doesn't end up in another app? Since the user may simply navigate away from the app, so logging out is not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a different `session_name()` for each app, the sessions are effectively inert from one another.

```
// Application 1
session_name("APP1");
session_start();

// Application 2
session_name("APP2");
session_start();
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could set different session names. I'm guessing that they are tied to each specified application right?

Comment: if each application has its own session name,then yes. the session_name basically ends up being the name of the cookie that the session ID is stored in. So if each app has its own unique session name, the user'll end up with one cookie per app, and each of those sessions will be independent of each other. The alternative is using subkeys in the session `$_SESSION['app1'][...]`, `$_SESSION['app2'][...]`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The solution I can think of would be including the application that the person is using in the session data, and if you see the wrong session in the user's session data, you destroy the session.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: maybe you'd want to set up a subdomain for each one of your apps. That way the cookies and sessions are completely separate automatically, rather than relying on a function (which may be slow, as one person indicated in the `session_name()` manual comments.)

In addition, I believe separate subdomains keep you safer from exploits because of the same origin policy.  (Right?)

Comment: Not really. Depends on how the cookies are set. Usually they're set on the parent domain, so a cookie from site1.example.com will still see cookies from site2.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like session sections by using different keys for every application. You just need to be sure to have the keys unique. Everytime you save some data into session save it in the proper section e.g.:

```
//save the ids into db or configuration file after it's generated
$app1id = uniqid('fbApp');
$app2id = uniqid('fbApp');

//Save data for application 1
$_SESSION[$app1id] = array('app' => 'data');

//Save data for application 2
$_SESSION[$app2id] = array('app' => 'data');
```